# Passing String to another forms from one form in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Pass String to another forms from one form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871958/how-to-pass-string-to-another-forms-from-one-form-in-c-sharp)

C# Query : When I login to my software I select the desired username using combobox. After I login, I want to see the username text in the main window on the toolstrip.

I tried get and set method but something is going wrong.  Can you please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Form 1:

```
public partial class login : Form
{
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string username
    {
        get{
            return a.ToString();}
    }

    public string a;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = comboBox1.Text;
        Form main1 = new main();
        main1.Show();
     // rest is the code for login.
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string username
    {
        set { toolStripLabel1.Text = value; }
    }
    private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form home = new home();
        home.MdiParent = this;
        home.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        home.Show();
    }
}
```

Here Home is form3 a childform which  opens in Main form. at load event of Main form itself.

Comment: You never open the Form 2 from Form 1. They don't "talk" in any way. where do you open Form 2?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL - form 2 is already open, it's the main form.

Comment: No form 2 is nt already open.. i edited n corrected d question.. have a look

Comment: You should've edited this code in your previous question instead of starting a new one. It helps people keep track of your actions and also helps you to get faster and better answers. Also as mentioned. This questions was answered in your previous question. If you have any questions about that answers, post a specific comment or edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Skalli Dude i am new here u can see it by my reputation points.. I'll see to it in next time. Thank u

Comment: @rick evans: I can only recommend you to read the faq. It has very sweet information on how you should ask questions and post answers. Asking the questions right will give you the answers you are seeking and some nice reputation on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the main_Load code with this:

```
private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    login home = new login();
    home.MdiParent = this;
    home.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    home.ShowDialog(); // waits for the home form to be closed

    this.username = home.username;
}
```

Comment: You have to set home.username's visibility to public for this to work

Comment: home.username's visibility is already set to public (in the login class)

Comment: yup, didn't notice it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Somebody just answered this question for you a few minutes ago!? And as far as I could tell, it was a perfectly appropriate answer, so why don't you just implement that?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9872043/1017882

Comment: Hey i dint get the previous one so i thought of sharing the code as well...

Comment: Should have really shared it in the other thread in my opinion. "Something is going wrong." What do you mean? What's the error? Instead of declaring a Form called home, you should declare a login (also reconsider the naming with regards to capital letters), and then pull the username string from this login form.

Comment: Error is Value is not getting passed using d above method.. i want to know where i am doing wrong.. kindly help with the same

Comment: The is a comment not an answer. You should delete it and flag the question to be closed if you thinks it's a duplicate.

Comment: Well where in your code do you expect the value to be 'passed'? Your main form is the form that wants this value, and yet doesn't seem to be retrieving it in any way. If you've coded the login form correctly, you should have a string of username data stored in the username property on your login form, all you have to do is, once the user has made a selection, access this username property from your main form.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty I have accessed username property using set method in main form... it should work right ? its nt working... :O

Comment: You haven't. You've got another entirely different property (one which now belongs to the main form) called username. login.username is what you're after. Although note it'll be [nameOfYourLoginInstance].username, so I'd recommend something like loginForm.username. You need to read properly over your code yourself now, and if you honestly can't grasp it you should spend a few hours reading into fundamental OOP principals. I literally can't explain it any differently, I could code it for you but then you'll just come stuck on the next little OOP problem.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty Dude i am still stucked with the same problem... can u please help with the code.. so i'll get it..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you call your login class.
But you could pass an instance of your main form and set the value from there.

```
public login(main mainInstance)
{
    //... login etc.

    mainInstance.UserName = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

or have the login method return a user object or string.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post this as a comment, otherwise it would be unreadable, but unless I am mistaken:

```
Form home = new home()
```

Would not even compile considering the only two classes are `main` and `login`

While you could correct the code and declare the form the correct way

```
login home = new login();
```

It seems easier just to use a `static` variable in a case like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe best way is to use events:

Form1:

```
public partial class login : Form
{
    public delegate void sendStringDelegate(string s);
    public event sendStringDelegate sendString;

    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string username
    {
        get{
            return a.ToString();}
    }

    public string a;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = comboBox1.Text;
        sendString(a);
     // rest is the code for login.
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    login log = new login();

    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        log.sendString += new login.sendStringDelegate(setString);
    }

    public void setString(string s)
    {
        whatever.text = s;
    }

    public string username
    {
        set { toolStripLabel1.Text = value; }
    }
    private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form home = new home();
        home.MdiParent = this;
        home.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        home.Show();
    }
}
```

code not tested so there might be some errors

Also you could use static event:

change 
`public event sendStringDelegate sendString;` 
to 
`public static event sendStringDelegate sendString;`

remove `login log = new login();`

change 
`log.sendString += new login.sendStringDelegate(setString);`
to 
`login.sendString += new login.sendStringDelegate(setString);`